# What is the correct way of returning an empty queryset in a Django View?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a ListView in Django whose get_queryset() method will sometimes need to return no results.  I've tried three ways to do this:

1. `return EmptyQuerySet()`
2. `return Model.objects.none()`
3. `return Model.objects.filter(pk=-1)`

Each one of these returns a slightly different object.

1. `django.db.models.query.EmptyQuerySet` with its model attribute set to `None`
2. `django.db.models.query.EmptyQuerySet` with its model attribute set to `Model`
3. `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` with its model attribute set to `Model`

Only the third option works with the class based ListView.  The other options crash on an attribute error when the ListView tries to access the model attribute.  This surprises me and is a pain as it requires me to import Model in places where that can cause MRO issues.

What am I doing wrong/what should I be doing differently?

**Update**: The question then is, what is the right way to return an empty queryset via the class view method `get_queryset()`?

**Update**: Here is the line in Django's generic views that hits an attribute error when trying access the `model` attribute: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L166.

Comment: Why can't you use the second option, `EmptyQuerySet` has a model attribute in that case.

Comment: Just thinking about it makes me think you've got the wrong logic setup if you need to have an empty queryset in a listview. You should be able to handle that without a crash or so.

Comment: @akshar: you would think, but Django still throws an Attribute error on this line: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L166

Comment: @limelights: Having a list view with 0 items is a perfectly reasonable result.  Customer x has 0 orders for example.

Comment: Of course, but that shouldnt be an empty queryset. It should be handled by the template.

Comment: @limelights: not sure we are talking about the same thing.  I don't believe Django's ListView should crash if my get_queryset() method returns an EmptyQuerySet() or a Model.objects.none() response.

Comment: What does MRO mean in this context?

Answer (score 85):

I think the best way to accomplish this is to call [`none()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#none) on `objects` for your respective model, and return the result. Assuming your model is named `Entry`:

```
queryset = Entry.objects.none()
```

Comment: Why is this the preferred method when compared to the other methods that the author asks about?

Comment: @SebastianGaweda "Calling none() will create a queryset that never returns any objects and no query will be executed when accessing the results." Cause its fast cause it doesnt hit the DB

Comment: `.union` not working with this approach